# How to handle auth and remember client on Websocket Endpoint in c#

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, .net-core, websocket

I am very new in websockets area. I am trying to figure out the auth for websocket endpoint in c#. The service already has its auth which works for http endpoints. Few questions I had are

- Would I need to handle the auth for websocket endpoint differently? Also once the handshake happens, would we need to authenticate the requests again?
- Do we need to maintain the state of clients on server corresponding to the requests? If yes, what are the recommended approach for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The websocket connection is established by upgrading an http request. If you have some kind of authentication already working for http requests, then you need to make sure that this authentication is applied before the upgrade happens, so that no upgrade can take place unless the request has been authenticated. How you do this depends on the specifics of your system.

Once the websocket connection has been established using a properly authenticated http request as the starting point, authentication is not applicable anymore in the context of the websocket. There is nothing you have to do. There is no such thing as requests that you have to authenticate. The websocket is a bi-directional stream of messages in an established session.

And yes, the concept of a session does always imply client state, so your server will have to have knowledge of every single websocket client which is at any moment connected. At the very least you need to keep the connection object alive, so that you can read messages from it and write messages to it.

Comment: Thanks Mike for answering. 

Could you refer to me some resource or some ways on state management of client on websocked server?

Comment: Sorry, I have no such source. But a) it is trivial, so I do not see why you are fretting about it, and b) you can make it non-trivial if you wish, but then it will be highly dependent on what you are trying to accomplish, which nobody knows, therefore nobody can give you advise.